# Log firing of triggers in postgres 9.1

Tags: postgresql, logging, triggers, postgresql-9.1

We have DB that has massive amount of business logic stored in triggers inside DB. Is there a way to log firing of triggers along with arguments that they have been fired, and what they have changed?

I saw a lot of tutorials on how to do table audit with triggers, but I would like to audit triggers not tables :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take one of the examples that do table auditing with triggers. Use their approach to extract the changed data, but do not write the data into an audit table, but use it for a `RAISE NOTICE`.

That notice will then be written to the PostgreSQL log file if you set the logging configuration correctly (`log_min_messages = notice`)

See the manual for details on RAISE: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html