# PostgreSQL log trigger/function query data

Tags: postgresql, function, logging, triggers, audit

We have business logic in SQL queries (~200 triggers), that supplement our application code. and we have some bugs in it -to find them I would like to see all transactions that change anything on the database (instead of checking 40 tables by hand).

We enabled logging in `/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf` by setting:

```
log_statement = 'mod' # none, ddl, mod, all
```

This logs all INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE statements from the application correctly, like so:

```
INSERT INTO misc.object_types (uuid, object_type_schema, object_type_table) VALUES 'e49fcebd-e8f4-4ca4-b664-e7194685ae3f', 'gis', 'lines')
```

But the actions performed by SQL functions are not logged. Setting

```
track_functions = all # none, pl, all
```

in the conf file does show that the trigger/function got executed. But I am interested in the actual SQL statement with all values, just like with `log_statement= 'mod'`

Now I have found some topics here, but they all rely on manually creating an `audit table` or manually logging with `RAISE` (like this one [Log firing of triggers in postgres 9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904234/log-firing-of-triggers-in-postgres-9-1)).

- How can I enable logging of queries executed by triggers/functions without manual (error-prone) code?
- Even more important: Why are triggers/functions handled differently than regular queries? Does that also mean that a trigger calls a different INSERT than a manual INSERT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`log_statement` will log only top-level statements, that is statements sent by the client. Nested statements are not logged.

One way to log those is to use the `auto_explain` contrib module. You'll have to enable it, set `auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on` and `auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0`. Then all statements, even nested ones, will be logged, along with their execution plan.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz-Albe for this pointer! 

Now I do get the log output, but with variables instead of values. 
`INSERT INTO misc.object_types (uuid, object_type_schema, object_type_table, label) VALUES (NEW.uuid, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME, NEW.label) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`
Any idea on how to drill down further? Instead of the variable name _NEW.uuid_ I would like to see the value that gets written to database (i confirmed that i have a value in the db). I could not find a switch in EXPLAIN nor AUTO_EXPLAIN.

Comment: For more, you have to sprinkle your code with `RAISE NOTICE` to output the data.